# How to integrate $\int_0^\alpha x\ln|\frac{x-1}{x+1}| dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate
$$
\int_0^\alpha 2x\ln|\frac{x-1}{x+1}| dx
$$
where $\alpha>1$.

Attempts:
Integrate by parts, we have
$$
\alpha^2\ln|\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+1}|-\int_0^\alpha \frac{2x^2}{x^2-1} dx
$$
The second part diverges when evaluate by Mathematica.

Comment: Do you want $\int_0^\alpha f'(x)dx$ to denote a suitable regularization, such as $f(\alpha)-f(0)$ or $\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_0^{1-\epsilon}f'(x)dx+\int_{1+\epsilon}^\alpha f'(x)dx\right)$?

Comment: @J.G. If the integral can be evaluate in the general sense (your first case), it will be better.

Comment: If that's your preferred interpretation, determine the family of antiderivatives. But be warned: the $+C$ will only be _locally_ constant, which is why this isn't the end of the regularization story. [What do you want it for, by the way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Comment: @J.G. I don't understand your comment. I just want the numerical value of a definite integral. If it exists, how do I get it? Else, why doesn't it exist. I think the question is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x \rightarrow 1$, the logarithm term goes to negative infinity. This means that the function being integrated, and hence the integral, is not well defined. The standard approach when this happens is to break the integral into two improper integrals and check their respective behaviour very carefully:

$\begin{eqnarray} \int_0^\alpha 2x \log \left | \frac{x - 1}{x + 1} \right | dx & = & \int_0^1 2x \log \left | \frac{x - 1}{x + 1} \right | dx + \int_1^\alpha 2x \log \left | \frac{x - 1}{x + 1} \right | dx \\
& = & \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_0^{1-\epsilon} 2x \log \left | \frac{x - 1}{x + 1} \right | dx + \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{1+\epsilon}^\alpha 2x \log \left | \frac{x - 1}{x + 1} \right | dx \\
& = & \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_0^{1-\epsilon} 2x \log \left ( \frac{1 - x}{1 + x} \right ) dx + \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{1+\epsilon}^\alpha 2x \log \left ( \frac{x - 1}{x + 1} \right ) dx \\
 \end{eqnarray}$

Notice that I changed the sign in the first logarithm since we know that $x - 1 < 0$ in that region.

You can find both integrals through a combination of integration by parts to remove the logarithmic terms and then polynomial division and partial fractions to reduce the remaining rational functions, which will give you two limits, which you can then evaluate to get an expression for the overall integral. If the two limits do not both converge, then the total integral is not well defined. My quick scratchings suggest that it probably will converge, but that it's not trivial to do so (and involves invoking l'Hospital on both sides).

Comment: What if the two integral both are not convergent, but their sum converges? In this case, can we say the integral have a definite value?

Comment: @anoffercan'trefuse It would have [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), if you want some jargon.

Answer (score 0):

Problem :
$$=\int _0^{\alpha }x\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)dx$$

Use integrate by parts and you will get :
$$=\frac{x^2\ln \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)}{2}-\int \frac{x^2\left(x+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1-x}{\left(x+1\right)^2}\right)}{2\left(x-1\right)}dx\:$$

Simplify :
$$=\frac{x^2\ln \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)}{2}-\int \frac{x^2}{\left(x-1\right)\left(x+1\right)}dx\:$$

Perform polynomial long division :
$$=\frac{x^2\ln \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)}{2}-\int \left(\frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)\left(x+1\right)}+1\right)dx\:$$

Solve it :
$$=\frac{x^2\ln \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)}{2}-x\:-\:\int \:\frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)\left(x+1\right)}dx\:$$

Simplify to calculate :
$$=\frac{x^2\ln \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)}{2}-x+\:\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}dx\:$$

Use common integral :
$$=\frac{x^2\ln \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)}{2}-x+\frac{\ln \left|x+1\right|}{2}-\frac{\ln \left|x-1\right|}{2}$$

Input the limit and we will get :
$$=\frac{\left(\alpha ^2-1\right)\ln \left(\frac{\alpha -1}{\alpha +1}\right)-2\alpha -2}{2}+\frac{\ln \left(-1\right)+2}{2}$$

Simplify and rewrite the answer :
$$\frac{\left(\alpha ^2-1\right)\ln \left(\frac{\alpha -1}{\alpha +1}\right)-2\alpha +\ln \left(-1\right)}{2}\:for\:\alpha >0$$